# Getting rid of commas and parentheses

Tags: python

I'm writing a program for my intro to scripting class that is supposed to divide user_num by x 3 times.

here is my code:

```
user_num = int(input())
x = int(input())

import math

num1 = user_num / x
num2 = num1 / x
output = math.trunc(user_num / x), math.trunc(num1 / x), math.trunc(num2 / x)

print(output)
```

Say that input was 200, output looks like this:

```
(100, 50, 25)
```

which is all fine and dandy, except for the grading program in my course expects the output to have no commas or parentheses

```
100 50 25
```

I've tried using `output.replace(',', ' ')`
as well as `output.strip(',')` 
to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried `print(*output)` ?

Comment: `print(f"{100} {100 / 2} {100 / 4}")`

Comment: @Mous only if the OP converts their numeric values to strings first... otherwise it'll be an error

Comment: Thanks, Jon. Good catch